# .htaccess mod_rewrite Conditional Issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want a IF/ELSE condition of redirecting a URL...

Basically, I want to redirect all the 13-digit numeric links, to a specific URL (then add that 13 digits). And, also want to redirect all the non 13-digit links to another URL.

So, if the request_uri is exactly of 13 digits, redirect it to an URL. If not 13, then redirect to another URL.

Please solve this simple issue.

(I just tried the following, but it is not working)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([0-9]{13})$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{13}) https://domain1.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the condition which will never match a request. Take a look into the documentation of the tools you use. It clearly states that the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable will contain the *absolute* path of the requested URI. So a path with a leading slash (`). However such a condition is not actually requested at all, simple rules are absolutely adequate for such a task:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]{13})/?$ https://domain1.example.com/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ https://domain2.example.com/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Just one more thing to clarify (since I have not mentioned it in my original post above)...

First of all, there will be NO trailing slash, in my URLs. Just the numeric values. It will be exactly 13 digits, so that, it will be redirected to another URL (with that value off course). But, if for some cases, that numeric variable is any value, other than 13 digits, the code will then redirected to another URL. That's all.

Comment: So...

https://example.com/1908141534144 (exactly 13 digits) will be redirected to https://example.com/pages/1908141534144
https://example.com/19081415 (any value, other than 13 digits) will be redirected to https://example.com/new/19081415


So, in your example, the leading and trailing slashes are not necessary, I guess. Can you please modify your code according to this message of mine and let me know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused... Every request URI has a leading slash, there is nothing you can do about that. The `^/?` in the rule patterns only serves the purpose that the rule can be used likewise in the real http server's host configuration or in dynamic configuration files without altering the rule. Both rules accept, but do not required a trainling slash, so it is optional. That is what usually makes sense. Do I get you right that you really want to redirect to different hosts depending on whether a trailing slash is specified or not? That would be surprising, but certainly possible.

Comment: OK! Sorry about the 'Leading Slash' confusion! Yes, after the domain extension, there would be a leading slash, off course. But, after those numeric variables, there will NOT be any trailing slash. So, please let me know the final code, upon seeing my requirements (mentioned in my earlier comments here). In short, a 13-digit numeric variable (with a leading slash) will redirect to one type of URL. Any other numbers (apart from being 13-digit) will redirect to another URL. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: That did not really answer my question. I understood that 13-digit numbers should be redirected different than any other number, so longer or shorter ones. No need in repeating that multiple times. The question is how a 13-digit number with trailing slash should get handled: as if specified without trailing slash (usual and intuitive web behavior) or different (unexpected, but possible). So what do you want? If the trailing slash should make a difference then you just need to remove the trailing `/?` from the rule patterns which atches exactly such slash in an optional manner.

Comment: Just tweaked your code a little and it is perfectly working now, as desired. Many thanks for the help! <3